# GenericForeignKeys in Intermediate Models

Tags: django, django-models, generic-foreign-key

I'm attempting to create an intermediate model, Permissions, between 'auth.Group' and any other custom models; this will serve as permissions or a means of what is visible to which groups.

I have been able to create an intermediate model, ExamplePermissions, between 'auth.Group' and one model.

```
    class Example(TimeStampable, Ownable, Model):
        groups = models.ManyToManyField('auth.Group', through='ExamplePermissions', related_name='examples')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        ...
        # Used for chaining/mixins
        objects = ExampleQuerySet.as_manager()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class ExamplePermissions(Model):
        example = models.ForeignKey(Example, related_name='group_details')
        group = models.ForeignKey('auth.Group', related_name='example_details')
        write_access = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        def __str__(self):
            return ("{0}'s Example {1}").format(str(self.group), str(self.example))
```

However, the issue is that this opposes reusability.  To create a model that allows any custom model to be associated with it, I implemented a GenericForeignKey in place of a ForeignKey as follows:

```
    class Dumby(Model):
        groups = models.ManyToManyField('auth.Group', through='core.Permissions', related_name='dumbies')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Permissions(Model):
        # Used to generically relate a model with the group model
        content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='group_details')
        object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
        #
        group = models.ForeignKey('auth.Group', related_name='content_details')
        write_access = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        def __str__(self):
            return ("{0}'s Content {1}".format(str(self.group), str(self.content_object)))
```

Upon attempting to make migrations, it errors with:
core.Permissions: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'simulations.Dumby.groups', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Dumby' or 'Group'.

At first glance, using a GenericForeignKey in an intermediate table seems like a dead end.  If this is the case, is there some generally accepted way of handling such a situation besides the cumbersome and redundant approach of creating a custom intermediate model for each custom model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use ManyToManyField when using GenericForeignKey in your intermediate model; instead, use GenericRelation, so your groups field would be simply declared as:

```
groups = generic.GenericRelation(Permissions)
```

See [reverse generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations) for more details.

Comment: The intermediate model does not have a ManyToManyField; note that Permissions is the intermediate model

Comment: I meant to say "do not use ManyToManyField in Dumby...". Hopefully you get my point now, which is to replace ManyToManyField with GenericRelation.